# mysql group by methods

Tags: php, mysql

Purchase Table:

```
========================
id|username|product|price|
01|Desmond |tv     |$40  |
02|Desmond |watch  |$20  |
03|Desmond |ring   |$30  |
04|Desmond |laptop |$40  |
========================
```

Product Table:

```
============================
id|product|type |promotion_ID|
01|tv     |big  |001         |
02|watch  |small|002         |
03|ring   |small|002         |
04|laptop |big  |001         |
============================
```

Promotion ID:

```
==============================
id|promotion_ID|promotion_name|
01|001         |mid-year      |
02|002         |end-year      |
==============================
```

I want to display the result from the Purchase table based on while loop method to display all information from mysql which is no problem, but I want to group them, accordingly to their promotion id/promotion name based on purchase table. May I know, how can I go about it?

For e.g.
Display Result:

Mid-year

```
=======================
username|product|price|
Desmond |tv     |$40  |
Desmond |laptop |$40  |
=======================
```

End-year

```
=======================
username|product|price|
Desmond |watch  |$20  |
Desmond |ring   |$30  |
=======================
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks you everyone for your help, managed to get the desired result in another way.. Once again, thanks for contributing help..

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for `ORDER BY` and `JOIN`:

```
SELECT promotion_name, 
    username, 
    p.product,
    price
FROM Purchase P
    JOIN Product PR ON P.Product=PR.Product
    JOIN Promotion PO ON PR.Promotion_Id=PO.Promotion_Id
ORDER BY promotion_name, p.product
```

In regards to your database, I would not recommend storing the Product in the Purchase table -- you should be storing the Product_Id instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
This may help you..

Select username,product,price from Purchase
Join Product on Product.product = Purchase.product 
Join Promotion On promotion.promotion_ID  = Product.promotion_ID
where promotion_name = 'mid-year' // pass your argument
Order by Product.product
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT pur.username, pur.product, pur.price
FROM tbl_purchase pur 
INNER JOIN tbl_product pro USING(product)
INNER JOIN tbl_promotion prm USING(promotion_ID)
ORDER BY prm.promotion_name
```

**NOTE:** you havn't reference primary key with all tables,  so make index on column `product` and `promotion_id` on all tables